# How to safelly call a C++ function by JNA from multiple threads?

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, java-native-interface, jna

I use JNA to call a function in a dynamic library written in C++. I noticed that a segmentation fault occurs when the C++ function in the library is called from multiple threads.

My question is how to call a C++ function **in parallel** via JNA without segmentation fault. In my C++ code, nothing of outside data is referenced, so I believe executing the C++ function in parallel is possible.

I'm sure that multi-threading is the cause of the segmentation fault because making the method synchronized suppressed the problem. In other words. In other words, I know that adding a `synchronize` or using `Native.synchronizedLibrary()` resolve the segmentation fault by executing the C function in serial way. However, I hope to run the C++ function in parallel due to performance issue.

```
public static interface MyCLibrary extends Library{
   ...
}

public static class RunnerClass implements Runnable{

  public void run(){
    callCfunc()
  }

  // Making this method synchronized suppress the error
  public void callCfunc(){
    MyCLibrary INSTANCE =  (MyCLibrary)Native.loadLibrary(MyCLibrary.JNA_LIBRARY_NAME, MyCLibrary.class);
    INSTANCE.cFunc()
  }
}

public static class MainClass {
  public static void main(){
      // When numThread = 1, the error does NOT occurr
      int numThread = 2;
      ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThread);
      for (int i = 0; i < numThread; i++) {
          es.execute(new RunnerClass()));
      }
      es.shutdown();
      try {
          es.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

  }
}
```

Comment: Post your C++ code.  Perhaps it's not reentrant?

Comment: @AndrewHenle thank you and probably your guess is true. After another research and your comment, now I believe reentrant occurs this problem.

Before posting this question, I thought that memory space for dynamic library is newly created for each thread and  not shared within multiple threads. But, my though seems to be wrong. I need to create thread-safe C++ code and obviously my C++ code is NOT thread-safe.

Comment: However, it's tough to update my C++ code to be thread-safe.
So, I think my question should be "how to create different memory space for dynamic library called from multi-thread in Java in order to avoid reentrant".

Should I update the original question or  close this and create new question?

Comment: Since it's the C++ code that not reentrant, IMO it'd be best to fix it there.  Create a static mutex, lock it upon entry into the method, and unlock it right before the method returns.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thank you but, I hope to execute C++ function **in parallel** due to performance issue.

Comment: I believe `reentrant` occurs the problem and learned that avoiding `reentrant` is one of the important thing to call C++ function safely in Java thread. So, I close this question and will create new one to ask a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I believe calling loadLibrary multiple times in parallel is what's causing the segfault.
You should load it once and pass to all of the instances of RunnerClass.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not solve the issue. I'm sorry for forgetting to mention that, but I've already tried that.